# Function call on Label.Text property - does not work

Tags: vb.net, function, properties, label

I'm new in all aspects. Trying to learn. I have the following function which I call on the Load event for the Form1 and I want to assign the function value to Label31.Text. And it doesn't show anything. In the SQL query i call for another public function, witch works, because I use it to set another Label text property. What can be wrong?

```
 Public Shared Function nranagajati() As Integer
    Dim totalangajati As Integer
    Dim startDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234")
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Prezenti FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$PrezentaSchimb] WHERE  ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "') AND (cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) AS datetime) = @data2)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", startDate)
            con.Open()
            totalangajati = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
    Return totalangajati
End Function
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that an exception is being thrown.  Have you debugged the code?  Have you checked whether an exception message is being displayed in the Output window?  Look for the message first and, if it's not there, debug, i.e. set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line.

Comment: I never see you try to do anything with labels in what you've shown us. Are you sure the function doesn't return anything/an exception is thrown?

Comment: As an aside, a `Using` block for your Sql Connection would make the code look a little cleaner.

Comment: Hello! Thanks alot for replies! It seemed that the label wasnt refreshing. I added a Me. Refresh after the function call and it is working... Strange. Because the other labels wich were all calling functions were working without Refresh().

Comment: in any case, something like this `SELECT Prezenti FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$PrezentaSchimb] WHERE  ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "') AND (cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) AS datetime) = @data2)` has potential to return `DbNull`, which will make this `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` throw an error